# Should I put a dash in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

I wrote this sentence:

> In conclusion, the reading claims that minimum wage is harmful to the companies, which the lecturer contradicts by providing three points –which form a compelling argument, to illustrate his viewpoint.

I don't know if it is grammatically correct to use `-` before `which` and I don't know if I should replace the `,` with `-`.

Answer (score 2):

First, it should be an em dash, not a hyphen.  (If you cannot produce an em dash, a double hyphen is generally considered an acceptable substitute.)  Second, you must use the em dash on both sides of the clause it offsets.

> In conclusion, the reading claims that minimum wage is harmful to the companies, which the lecturer contradicts by providing three points—which form a compelling argument—to illustrate his viewpoint.

Comment: would it be better if i said `In conclusion, the reading claims that minimum wage is harmful to the companies, contradicted by the lecturer in three points, which together form a compelling argument illustrating his view` ?

Comment: Both sides—**unless** it is the first or last clause which is to be demarcated

Comment: @StoneyB what do you mean please ? this is the conclusion of my essay, nothing after it will be written.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, he's referring to the case when you write something like "which the lecturer contradicts by providing three points--which form a compelling argument."  Since the clause that starts out with the '--' is the last clause in the sentence, you don't put another '--' at the end of the clause; instead you use the period to end the entire sentence.